# SQL Server - return column types of query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a query, I want to return an information row that shows the types of each column returned.

I researched using:

```
SELECT system_type_name 
FROM 
sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
('select * from table', NULL, 0) ;
```

That gives what I want for simple select statements:

[image]

But when using this for the select statements I want to run I get the following errors:

[image]

What alternatives are there for grabbing columns for results set of a query?

Comment: Show us the query that generated the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need below two Query's one of them

for Datatype and Length

```
 use yourdatabasename;



 SELECT c.name AS 'Column Name',
       t.name + '(' + cast(c.max_length as varchar(50)) + ')' As 'DataType',
       case 
         WHEN  c.is_nullable = 0 then 'null' else 'not null'
         END AS 'Constraint'
  FROM sys.columns c
  JOIN sys.types t
    ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
   WHERE c.object_id    in ( Object_id('ordertable'), Object_id('Course'))
```

---here ordertable,Course is two table name

---

```
SELECT 
    c.name 'Column Name',
    t.Name 'Data type',
    c.max_length 'Max Length',
    c.precision ,
    c.scale ,
    c.is_nullable,
    ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'Primary Key'
FROM    
    sys.columns c
INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTableName')
```

Comment: How can I replace "use yourdatabasename" with a query?

Comment: i mean your database name like use Test; here Test is a database name

Comment: Sorry, I see. Where do I insert the query in your example?

Comment: @BDillan your question is you want to know your column name and data type from your table ?right

Comment: I have a query that selects data from multiple tables. It returns a few columns of data and I want to figure out those column types. I'm wondering how to do this using your code

Comment: lest say your table name is "ordertable and Course" then check my answer where clause option what i put just replace your table name there or give me your table name i will change according to that

Comment: It's not a table, it's a query. e.g. "SELECT * FROM TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON Id = TableB.Id"

Comment: When I put that in OBJECT_ID('...') it does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177297/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-bdillan).